# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\tan\frac{x}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\tan\frac{x}{2^n}$.

My attempt:

Let $S$ = $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}$ $tan{\frac{x}{2^n}}$

$\int S dx$ = $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\int \frac{1}{2^n}$ $tan{\frac{x}{2^n}} dx$

= $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\ln \sec {\frac{x}{2^n}}$

= $\ln(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\sec {\frac{x}{2^n}})$

not sure how to proceed with this,

Due to the limitations of my school syllabus, I would greatly appreciate a solution involving complex numbers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $\sec x=\dfrac1{\cos x}$ , and $\sin2t=2\sin t\cos t$. Replace the upper limit of your product with *N*, then multiply the entire expression with $\csc\bigg(\dfrac x{2^N}\bigg)=\dfrac1{\sin\bigg(\dfrac x{2^N}\bigg)}$, and see what happens $\ldots$

Comment: ah yes. thank you very much :)